# How can I return/How can I convert dataset to a list of objects (List<ComponenetData>) in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I return/How can I convert dataset to a list of objects (List) in C#?

```
public static DataSet GetComponentData(int CustomerId, int UserId)
{

    string connectionString = ConfigurationReader.ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();            
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetComponentData", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CustomerId;
        command.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;
        da.SelectCommand = command;
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
            connection.Close();
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strError = ex.ToString();                   
            return ds = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            da = null;
            command = null;
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

**I need to return the result as a list eg.List.  I have done this by :**

```
 public static string GetGenericListData(string folderName, int CustomerId)
 {
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // List<Device>lstDevices=new List<Device>();
     Devices lstDevices = new Devices();
     DataSet ds=new DataSet();
     try 
     {
         ds = GetComponentData(CustomerId, UserId);
         if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)
         {

              foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
              {
                    Device  _PptDevices=new Device();                        
                   _PptDevices.Country = ((dr["Country"]) != null) ? Convert.ToString(dr["Country"]) : "";
                   _PptDevices.Area = ((dr["Area"]) != null) ? Convert.ToString(dr["Area"]) : "";
                   _PptDevices.Branch = ((dr["Branch"]) != null) ? Convert.ToString(dr["Branch"]) : "";
                   _PptDevices.SalesOffice = ((dr["Sales Office"]) != null) ? Convert.ToString(dr["Sales Office"]) : "";
                   _PptDevices.CustomerNumber = ((dr["Customer Number"]) != null) ? Convert.ToString(dr["Customer Number"

                   lstDevices.Add(_PptDevices);
                   _PptDevices = null;                   
              }

         }
     }
     catch 
     {


     }
     finally 
     {
     }
     string strStatus = "";
     if (lstDevices.Count > 0)
     {
         string FilePath = ConfigurationReader.FileLocation;
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Devices));
         MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
         serializer.Serialize(memStream, lstDevices);
         FileStream file = new FileStream  (folderName  "\\ComponentData.xml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

         memStream.WriteTo(file);
         file.Close();
         strStatus = "1"; //Success

     }
     else
     {
         strStatus = "0"; //Failure
     }
     return strStatus;
 }
```

Here what I am doing is getting dataset from one function and converting it as a list using another function. Is there any direct method to convert dataset to list more easier?  Or how can we assign the result set directly to the list.. 
**Is there any other simple solution?**

Comment: have you tried with with the `ToList()` method? You might have to go like `var list = ds.AsEnumerable().ToList()`

Comment: What does your `GetComponentData` returns? how does the structure looks like?

Comment: I have a property class. I need to get the result as  a list. List<Propertyclass>

Comment: Now I get the result as a dataset and then converting it as a list using that foreach loop. It works.. But is there more easier method?

Comment: You can store the result into a `DataTable` first and then add each row in the `List<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the Student be the class, then you can do something like the following:

```
dTable = ds.Tables[0];
List<Device> studentList=dTable.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Device() { 
                             Country =x["column_id"]!=null?x.Field<string>("column_id"):"",
                             Area = x["Area"]!=null?x.Field<string>("Area"):""
                             Branch = x["Branch"]!=null?x.Field<string>("Branch"):"",
                             SalesOffice = x["Sales Office"]!=null?x.Field<string>("Sales Office"):"",
                             CustomerNumber = x["Customer Number"]!=null?x.Field<string>("Customer Number"):""
                             }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to convert it to `DataSet` if you are interested in `List<>`, you could directly convert it from reader.

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var list = reader.Select(r => new Propertyclass() // specify the class name 
                  {
                       Id = r["id"] is DBNull ? null : r["id"].ToString(),
                       Name = r["name"] is DBNull ? null : r["name"].ToString() 
                  })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: I need to get the result as List<pptClass>, because I need to generate xml with pre-defined format.

Comment: @radhikas: better you edit the question with sample class that help him to update his answer, Hence you will get the exact req.